# Проблемы с курсором sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Только начал освоение sqlite, столкнулся с проблемой, есть приложение которое получает данные и записывает этот набор в базу, при первом запуске, когда база была пустая все прошло идеально. Теперь же, когда в ней есть данные я делаю следующее: проверяю есть ли уже такая запись в базе и если есть то хочу вывести её поле code. Но во время выполнения приложение вылетает, а в отладчике видно что кусок

```
`Log.d("DBINFORM", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbConnector.CODE)));`
```

выкидывает исключение "Method threw 'android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException' exception."
Обернул строку 
`Log.d("DBINFORM", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbConnector.CODE)));`
в условие, теперь приложение не вылетает, но метод cursor.moveToFrist() возвращает false.

Может я неправильно делаю выборку, вообще не пойму строка найдена или нет?) 
Код который работает с базой:

```
 private void soapScaner(SoapObject object){
   for(int i = 0; i<object.getPropertyCount();i++){
       if(object.getProperty(i) instanceof SoapObject) {
           String NomCode  = ((SoapObject)object.getProperty(i)).getProperty("Code").toString();
           Log.d("NomName",((SoapObject)object.getProperty(i)).getProperty("NomName").toString());
           db = dbConnector.getWritableDatabase();
           Cursor cursor = db.query(BasicSettings.Nom_DB_Table,new String[]{dbConnector.CODE},dbConnector.CODE+"=?",new String[]{NomCode},null,null,null);
           //Если товар найден то перезаписываем его текущие поля, а иначе добавляем новую строку в базу данных
           if(cursor != null){
             if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                  Log.d("DBINFORM", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbConnector.CODE)));
            }
           }else {
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put(dbConnector.CODE,((SoapObject)object.getProperty(i)).getProperty("Code").toString());
                cv.put(dbConnector.NOM_NAME,((SoapObject)object.getProperty(i)).getProperty("NomName").toString());
                cv.put(dbConnector.PARENT,((SoapObject)object.getProperty(i)).getProperty("Parent").toString());
                cv.put(dbConnector.IS_GROUP,((SoapObject)object.getProperty(i)).getProperty("IsGroup").toString());
                cv.put(dbConnector.EDO,((SoapObject)object.getProperty(i)).getProperty("EDO").toString());
                cv.put(dbConnector.KOEF_EDO,((SoapObject)object.getProperty(i)).getProperty("KoefEDO").toString());
                cv.put(dbConnector.EXO,((SoapObject)object.getProperty(i)).getProperty("EXO").toString());
                cv.put(dbConnector.KOEF_EXO,((SoapObject)object.getProperty(i)).getProperty("KoefEXO").toString());
                cv.put(dbConnector.PRICE,((SoapObject)object.getProperty(i)).getProperty("Price").toString());
                cv.put(dbConnector.REMAINDER,((SoapObject)object.getProperty(i)).getProperty("Remainder").toString());
                cv.put(dbConnector.REMAINDER_SEC,((SoapObject)object.getProperty(i)).getProperty("RemainderSec").toString());
               db.insert(BasicSettings.Nom_DB_Table,null,cv);

           }
           db.close();
           cursor.close();
           publishProgress(i,object.getPropertyCount());
       }
   }
}
```

Код который инициализировал таблицу в базе при первом запуске приложения:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table "+BasicSettings.Nom_DB_Table+" (" +
            KEY_ID+" integer primary key autoincrement," +
            CODE+" text," +
            NOM_NAME+" text," +
            PARENT+" text," +
            IS_GROUP+" boolean," +
            EDO +" text," +
            KOEF_EDO + " real," +
            EXO+" text," +
            KOEF_EXO+" real," +
            PRICE+" real," +
            REMAINDER+" integer," +
            REMAINDER_SEC+" integer );");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В запросе

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(BasicSettings.Nom_DB_Table,new String[]{dbConnector.CODE},dbConnector.CODE+"=?",new String[]{NomCode},null,null,null);
```

вы запрашиваете только один столбец из таблицы (второй параметр `String[] columns`), соответственно в курсор попадает только один столбец. И будет он под индексом `0`:

```
Log.d("DBINFORM",cursor.getString(0));
```

**Дополнение**

Хорошей практикой является обращение к полям курсора не прямо по числовому индексу, а по значению, полученному из метода `cursor.getColumnIndex("имя_столбца")`:

```
Log.d("DBINFORM",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbConnector.CODE)));
```

Тогда у вас такой ошибки бы даже не возникло.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Переписал так как вы сказали, дополнительно обернув вывод в лог условием if(cursor.moveToFirst()), оказывается этот метод возвращает false, типа первого элемента нет. Может я неправильно делаю выборку из базы?

Comment: Не пойму что вообще происходит с этим курсором) При первом запуске в него попадало значение null, я так понимаю потому что таблица была пустой, при втором запуске он не равен null, как я понимаю потому что он находит строку, но метод moveToFirst() возвращает false потому что не найдена строка?) Как это работает?

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос по новой проблеме. Только чуть более понятно. А то я сейчас не понял вас.

Comment: хорошо, сейчас сделаю